# Replicate a Firebase powered app in my own app (scraping data)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

App A uses firebase and receives notifications (observes) data from the server. I have seen the requests the app makes to the database and it opens a UDP connection which I believe is linked to this concept.

The app also communicates to this URL: https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen

The server pushes data to the app.

I'm wondering if its possible to observe for these in my own app? I have access to the Firebase AUTH token from analyzing the SSL data between app and server.

I'm essentially trying to scrape data but differently. I can successfully perform GET to get the info I desire, but the server blocks if I do it too quickly. App A receives data instantly ones the server sends it and I'm trying to replicate that as a customer listener in my program.

Answer (score 0):

The usecase is a little bit unclear to me, however it seems that you are looking for feature called "Snapshot Listeners". Not sure which language you want to use, however in every API I have seen, contain such listeners to Firestore data.

Examples from official google API's:
JS: `onSnapshot` ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot))
Java: `addSnapshotListner` ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#public-listenerregistration-addsnapshotlistener-activity-activity,-eventlistenerquerysnapshot-listener)), you can dig this documentation for others. But there are also third party APIs.

It seems that they work as you described. They listen to the object, to which they are attached (collection or document) If any change appear into it, such listener will receive data from Firebase Firestore.

I hope it will help!